# How to sign digitally with SHA-2 in PowerShell (NOT OpenSSL)

Tags: powershell, digital-signature, sha2

How can I sign digitally a string with SHA-2 by PowerShell script, not using OpenSSL? I know how to do it with OpenSSL, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it with .Net classes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) module provides easy access to the .NET types that do hashing via SHA-256/385/512 e.g.:

```
C:\PS> "This is a test" | Get-Hash -Algorithm SHA256


Algorithm: SHA256


Path       :
HashString : 309CB8ABAB6504945ACD10CE99546D2355AD5AE3B4CE99DA8ACCBC4EE7388EF9
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, @Keith Hill. But how do I use it for digital signature?

Comment: When I hear SHA-2 I think computing crypographic hashes.  When I hear digital signatures, I think authenticode signatures with certificates.  Perhaps you need the latter?  If so, you can create a self-signed cert on Windows using the MakeCert.exe utility.  Then you can use signtool.exe to apply a signature.  Both these tools require the Windows SDK. PowerShell also has Set-AuthenticodeSignature for applying a signature to a file.